# validate input for textbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am trying to validate textbox if there is a value. This textbox is within User control.

I tried to debug I am getting the following value.

```
input[id*=txtTitle]").val()



{"enabled":true,"emptyMessage":"","validationText":"","valueAsString":"","lastSetTextBoxValue":""}
```

How to validate this user control? please let me know.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#<%=Button2.ClientID %>").click(function () {
                var valid = true;
                var msg = "Please fill form:\n";
                if($("input[id*=txtTitle]").val().length == 0{ 
                    msg += "Title is Required!\n";
                    valid = false;
                }
</script>  


           <uc1:TextBoxWithCount ID="txtTitle" runat="server" MaxLength="200" ></uc1:TextBoxWithCount>
```

Comment: Are you using a client side debugging tool such as Firebug or Chrome Dev Tools to step through your Javascript?

Comment: yes I am using IE debugger.

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear.  When you say you are getting the first snippet as a value.  Is this what is being rendered to the screen? 

Is the second snippet exactly what you have in your .cshtml file?  I believe you will need a <script> tag wrapped around your javascript.

Comment: I edited my question. Yes there is <script> tag. I get this value when I debug Javascript. {"enabled":true,"emptyMessage":"","validationText":"","valueAsString":"","lastSetTextBoxValue":""}

Comment: So when you are debugging, where are you seeing that value?  Is that assigned to a variable of some sort?  Is that JSON returned from an ajax call?